# How to get the value of selected select using localStorage

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage

I'm trying to get the value of selected select using `localStorage.getItem()` but it gives me an error.

> Here is my select:

```
            <div class="field">
                <label>Work Area</label>
              <select class="ui fluid dropdown work_area" id="work_area" name="work_area">
                  <option selected value="">Select Work Area.</option>
                  <?php selectWorkArea(); ?>
              </select>

            </div>
```

> Here is my PHP function

```
 function selectWorkArea(){
    $conn = New Connection;
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT work_area FROM machine ORDER BY work_area ASC";
    $qry = $conn->select($sql,NULL,'0129180857');
    while($row= $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $work_area = $row->work_area;
        echo "<option data-value='$work_area' >$work_area</option>";
    }

 }
```

> here is my Javascript

```
 var select = document.querySelector(".work_area");
      var selectOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
      var lastSelected = localStorage.getItem('select');
      if(lastSelected) {
          select.value = lastSelected; 
      }
      select.onchange = function () {
        lastSelected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        console.log(lastSelected);
        localStorage.setItem('workarea', lastSelected);

     }
```

> And i got this error:
>   [Error image click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Feb4q.png)
>
> But when i tried to change my select into this  it works totally fine

```
        <div class="field">
                <label>Work Area</label>
                <select class="ui fluid dropdown work_area" id="work_area" name="work_area">
                  <option selected value="">Select Work Area.</option>
                  <option  data-value="1">1</option>
                  <option data-value="2">2</option>
                </select>
        </div>
```

[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOTt6.png)

Comment: You have `localStorage.getItem('select')` and `localStorage.setItem('workarea', lastSelected)` is it correct that you have 2 different names? because if i change `select` to `workarea` then it works.

Comment: Try changing `echo "<option data-value='$work_area' >$work_area</option>";` to `echo '<option data-value="$work_area" >$work_area</option>';`

Comment: can you give the output of `console.log(select)` before `select.value =`

Comment: Jason just change either `getItem('select')` to `getItem('workarea')` or `localStorage.setItem('workarea', lastSelected)` to `localStorage.setItem('select', lastSelected)`

Comment: I got it bro by removing the "data" in the `data-value` attribute. but my new problem is the data is remove when the page is refresh i tried to use this `localStorage.setItem('workarea',$('.work_area').val())` but still the data is removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for null before use.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("select") === null) {
  var lastSelected = localStorage.getItem('select');
  select.value = lastSelected; 
}
```

Comment: I got it bro by removing the "data" in the data-value attribute. but my new problem is the data is remove when the page is refresh i tried to use this localStorage.setItem('workarea',$('.work_area').val()) but still the data is removed

Comment: Set item on local storage when select change and rest  value when page reload.you can see sample demo created by me on  `https://jsfiddle.net/shree/sgb4888k/225/` . If you run fiddle  multi-pal time you can see a result.

Comment: thanks for the idea bro. i got it. i will post the answer here for anyone who need this. thanks.

Comment: Accept answer if its help you to find your problem. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by removing the `data` in the  `data-value` attribute. And after, i tried to refresh the page and the value of select is removed. that is not good. the solution is modify the javascript, here is the modification:

> Javascript code:

```
      $('#work_area').val(localStorage.workarea);
      localStorage.setItem('workarea','');
      var select = document.querySelector(".work_area");
      var selectOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
      var lastSelected = localStorage.getItem('select');
      if(lastSelected) {
          select.value = lastSelected; 
      }
      select.onchange = function () {
        lastSelected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        localStorage.setItem('workarea', lastSelected);

      }
```

> html code:

```
         <div class="field">
            <label>Work Area</label>
            <select class="ui fluid dropdown work_area" id="work_area" name="work_area">
              <option selected value="">Select Work Area.</option>
               <?php selectWorkArea(); ?>
             </select>
         </div>
```

> PHP function code:

```
 function selectWorkArea(){
    $conn = New Connection;
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT work_area FROM machine ORDER BY work_area ASC";
    $qry = $conn->select($sql,NULL,'0129180857');
    while($row= $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $work_area = $row->work_area;
        echo "<option value='$work_area' >$work_area</option>";
    }

}
```